# How to describe (get) one or list all Amazon Connect Customer Profiles with the AWS Amazon Connect Customer Profiles Boto3 API in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-connect

I am needing to list all and possibly get one Customer Profile using Python 3.10 and Boto3 in an AWS Lambda.

My approach to this is to use the [Customer Profiles Boto3 client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/customer-profiles.html) and its API method [list_profile_objects](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/customer-profiles/client/list_profile_objects.html) show in the code snippet below.

```
    import boto3    

    client = boto3.client('customer-profiles')

    response = client.list_profile_objects(
        MaxResults=100,
        DomainName=domainName,
        ObjectTypeName=<what_should_this_be>,
        ProfileId=<what_should_this_be>,
    )

    print(f"The Response {response}")
```

I am struggling with populating two required fields `ObjectTypeName` and `ProfileId`. Both are listed as required but when I use [list_profile_object_types](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/customer-profiles/client/list_profile_object_types.html) I get no results and if I'm trying to list all customer profiles, how will I know what any of the Id's are before hand??

Any help in the right direction on how to list all or get one (I may need this in the future) Amazon Connect Customer Profile would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to asking on Stack Overflow so appreciate any required patience, thanks so much.

Comment: `reactjs` with a `python` flag ?  what is the question ?  perhaps a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I apologize, I can remove the reactjs information if it adds too much information to the question, I didn't want to pigeon whole myself to using boto3 if there was a way to get this information on the frontend.

I can show examples of the API call I am attempting but each mentioned API call is a hyperlink that will take you to the documentation code snippet, which is what i will be sharing.

Thanks for the response.

Comment: well basically users need to be able to help you.  here is a good guide for how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have made several edits to question, does that make it easier to understand?

Answer (score 0):

The value for the `ObjectTypeName` field should be `CTR` if your account doesn't have any integrations. The possible values can be found from the CLI:

```bash
$ aws customer-profiles list-profile-object-type-templates --query 'Items[].SourceName' | jq -r .[] | uniq
Salesforce
Zendesk
CTR
Marketo
Servicenow
Segment
Shopify
$
```

According to the AWS documentation, only searching is supported by the API, as documented and shown in [Amazon Connect's amazon-connect-customer-profiles GitHub repo](https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-customer-profiles), using `aws customer-profiles search-profiles` and matching on at least one specific field.

As of June, 2023, [Amazon Connect : Administrator's Guide : Set up a real-time export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/set-up-real-time-export.html) explains how you may export new profiles and updates to existing profiles into a Kinesis Data Stream, which can be stored in something like DynamoDB for listing and querying?